# Order By ERROR , not showing

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by

> -- Trying to sort data using ORDER by with 2 SUBSTITUTION VARIABLE , but not working , problem is included below the thread.

Table: users

```
CREATE TABLE users
( 
user_id VARCHAR(5) ,
user_name VARCHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
)

/
INSERT INTO users
VALUES ('U01','User1')
/
INSERT INTO users
VALUES ('U02','User2')
/
```

Table: staffaccount

```
CREATE TABLE staffaccount
(
staffaccount_id VARCHAR(5) ,
user_id VARCHAR(5) ,
CONSTRAINT pk_staffaccount PRIMARY KEY(staffaccount_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_staffaccount1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
)
/
INSERT INTO staffaccount
VALUES ('STF01','U01')
/
INSERT INTO staffaccount
VALUES ('STF02','U02')
/
```

Table: location

```
CREATE TABLE location
(
location_id VARCHAR(5),
location_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_location PRIMARY KEY(location_id)
)
/
INSERT INTO location
VALUES ('LOC01','Staff Toilet')
/
INSERT INTO location
VALUES ('LOC02','Staff Office')
/
INSERT INTO location
VALUES ('LOC03','Staff Meeting Room')
/
INSERT INTO location
VALUES ('LOC04','Staff Hall')
/
```

Table: bookingstaff

```
CREATE TABLE bookingstaff
( 
staffaccount_id VARCHAR(5),
location_id  VARCHAR(5),
timebooked TIMESTAMP,
usages VARCHAR(25)
)

/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF01','LOC01',TIMESTAMP'2018-01-01 10:00:00','Pee')
/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF02','LOC02',TIMESTAMP'2018-01-02 10:00:00','Writing')
/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF01','LOC03',TIMESTAMP'2018-01-05 10:00:00','Meeting')
/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF02','LOC04',TIMESTAMP'2018-01-12 10:00:00','Dancing')
/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF01','LOC02',TIMESTAMP'2018-02-01 10:00:00','Writing')
/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF02','LOC03',TIMESTAMP'2018-02-02 10:00:00','Meeting')
/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF01','LOC02',TIMESTAMP'2018-02-15 10:00:00','Writing')
/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF02','LOC04',TIMESTAMP'2018-03-01 10:00:00','Dancing')
/
INSERT INTO bookingstaff
VALUES ('STF01','LOC03',TIMESTAMP'2018-03-02 10:00:00','Meeting')
/
```

> On the above is all my table query, try to use substitution variable
>   to display data. Code below

```
SELECT u.user_name,l.location_name,b.usages,to_char(cast(b.timebooked as date),'DD-MM-YYYY')as "DATE"
FROM staffaccount s
JOIN bookingstaff b
ON b.staffaccount_id = s.staffaccount_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u
ON u.user_id= s.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN location l
ON l.location_id= b.location_id
WHERE l.location_name LIKE '%Staff%'
AND timebooked
BETWEEN date&
AND date&
```

> with the code, here is the result for it. (first substitution
>   variable: '2017-01-01' , second substitution variable:'2018-02-10')

http://prntscr.com/iztftx  < Result displayed with myOra

> But when i tried to add ORDER by usages, it will show error.

Error:

> Never allowing me to enter second substitution variable

Comment: SELECT u.user_name,l.location_name,b.usages,to_char(cast(b.timebooked as date),'DD-MM-YYYY')as "DATE"
FROM staffaccount s
JOIN bookingstaff b
ON b.staffaccount_id = s.staffaccount_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u
ON u.user_id= s.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN location l
ON l.location_id= b.location_id
WHERE l.location_name LIKE '%Staff%'
AND timebooked
BETWEEN date&
AND date&
ORDER BY b.usages

Comment: Substitution variables should look like `&date1` and `&date2`. The ampersand comes BEFORE the variable name. And you need different names if you will input different values.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks ! will try the code ASAP, but was wondering why on the "working" query date& and date& works ?

Comment: Wait - I looked at the code more closely and I see what you are doing. You are using the `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'` syntax, which is correct. (If that was your intent). Then & by itself is seen as a placeholder for a substitution variable; and if you use a single & instead of &&, you will be prompted for individual values. Still better to write `between date &date1 and date &date2` for more clarity, and it shouldn't mess with your ORDER BY anymore either.

Comment: yeah , I see that the problem is placement error , should be &date and note date&, this is where the problem occurred. And @mathguy I have some question about , what the different between "GROUP BY" and "ORDER BY" ? is that possible i change my code to GROUP BY instead of ORDER BY ? or it is impossible to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be &var and not var&

```
WHERE l.location_name LIKE '%Staff%'
AND timebooked BETWEEN &date  AND &date    
ORDER BY  usages
```

and for a better readiblity

```
WHERE l.location_name LIKE '%Staff%'
AND timebooked BETWEEN &date1 AND &date2    
ORDER BY  usages
```

Comment: Thank you :) , the placement for "&" is wrong, after the changed , it work !